# Condition if for Nunit assert

Tags: c#, nunit, assert

I need to compare two `List`s by NUnit's `Assert.AreEqual`. If this statement is false (lists not the same) - then I need find elements in lists which not the same.

How I can use If statement for know- Assert return `true` or `false`?

Comment: The code will only proceed if the assert is true... you don' t need an if statement.

Comment: If the Assert fails no other code is executed. You need to change your strategy, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that nunit [CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4) is exactly what you were looking for.

This method compare between the collections. 
If a mismatch was found then the method will throw exception with the difference.

Comment: After your answer I deleted my hand crafted one. It's good to learn new things, thanks :-)

Comment: @PaoloCosta you welcome! That's what's great about our profession - every day we learn new things :-)

Comment: It is good solutions. Thank you, But what if I have a List with 3000 elements? AreEquvalent returns 2 Lists with differences and with all elements in List.
Maybe you know how I can filter differences element from AreEquvalent output?

Comment: Oh, sorry, this method return only 10 values from List. Very big thanks for you answer!! It is a good solution for me!

Comment: @PaoloCosta - thanks and you. Your answer was useful too! I'm added him to my luggage of knowledge =)

Comment: Ok, I undeleted it with an UPDATE :-) Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        List<int> a = new List<int>();
        List<int> b = new List<int>();

        //Fake data              
        a.Add(1);
        b.Add(2);
        b.Add(2);

        Assert.IsTrue(AreEquals(a,b), GetDifferentElements(a,b));
    }

    private string GetDifferentElements(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {

        if (AreEquals(a, b))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (a.Count != b.Count)
        {
            return "The two lists have a different length";
        }
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                s.Append(i.ToString() + " ");
            }
        }
        return string.Format("Elements at indexes {0} are different", s.ToString());
    }

    private bool AreEquals(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        if (a.Count != b.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Of course I was unaware of the CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent method provided in the accepted answer. That's a better solution of course!